# Incorrect syntax near '2290'

Tags: sql-server

Query:

```
INSERT INTO 2290_Form(FK_C_B_key,is_final_return,is_amendment,first_used_month,tax_year) 
VALUES ('CF3B908B-8120-493B-993A-B899A61AE77B',0,0,4,2014)
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '2290'.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Try to use `INSERT INTO [2290_Form](FK_C_B_key,is_final_return,is_amendment,first_used_month,tax_year) 
    VALUES ('CF3B908B-8120-493B-993A-B899A61AE77B',0,0,4,2014)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a table with a name that starts with a number. However, you can do this by enclosing the table name in `[]`. So in this instance, your query should be:

```
INSERT INTO [2290_Form] (FK_C_B_key,is_final_return,is_amendment,first_used_month,tax_year) 
    VALUES ('CF3B908B-8120-493B-993A-B899A61AE77B',0,0,4,2014)
```

As per [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962(v=sql.80).aspx):

> Rules for Regular Identifiers
>
> 1. The first character must be one of the following:
>
>    - A letter as defined by
>        the Unicode Standard 2.0. The Unicode definition of letters includes
>        Latin characters from a through z and from A through Z, in addition to
>        letter characters from other languages.
>    - The underscore (_), "at" sign (@), or number sign (#). Certain symbols
>        at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server.
>        An identifier beginning with the "at" sign denotes a local variable or
>        parameter. An identifier beginning with a number sign denotes a
>        temporary table or procedure. An identifier beginning with double
>        number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object.
>    - Some Transact-SQL
>        functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid
>        confusion with these functions, it is recommended that you do not use
>        names that start with @@.
> 2. Subsequent characters can be:
>
>    - Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 2.0.
>    - Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
>    - The "at" sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.
> 3. The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server
>      reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words.
> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
>
> **When used in Transact-SQL statements, identifiers that fail to comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.**

*Emphasis is mine.*

Answer (score 1):

Because your table name starts with a number you have to use `[]` arround your table name:

```
INSERT INTO [2290_Form](FK_C_B_key,is_final_return,is_amendment,first_used_month,tax_year) VALUES ('CF3B908B-8120-493B-993A-B899A61AE77B',0,0,4,2014
```